# Keyboard doesn't work in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I opened chrome and realized that the keyboard does nothing. I can't type any URLs or do Ctrl+T to open new tabs. It's like the keyboard isn't there. The keyboard works fine in all other applications. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. This is relatively new.

Chromium version is the latest available, apparently:

```
$ chromium --version
Chromium 96.0.4664.110 snap

$ sudo snap refresh chromium 
snap "chromium" has no updates available
```

How do I make my keyboard works with Chromium?

Comment: I realize it work in other apps... but can you try a different [physical] and see if that works. Ideally with a different brand

Comment: is mouse working? are you seeing mouse pointer, can you move it (and position it in the address bar)?

Comment: Mouse is fine, moving and clicking.  It's just the keyboard doesn't register in chrome only.

Comment: Are you using `ibus` or otherwise switch between inputs (Such as English/Japanese)?

Comment: you may try: `sudo apt install chrome --reinstall`. If you're not using the GOOGLE chrome, but chromium, remove the google-chrome  tag, if you use google-chrome REMOVE chromium tag, CHANGE TITLE to Google-Chrome

Comment: Could you provide the logs when you run it from the terminal? You can't even access to the developers tools? Ctrl+Shift+I. Wayland or X11?

Answer (score 4):

It is old question, but as I myself run time-to-time into same problem, it is good to have a point where everyone can recall it. For me the saver is following command line:

```
$ ibus exit
```

I hope it helps you too.